# Error adding columns to SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on Flask and sqlite as database. The requirements keep increasing for the project, so I have to add columns but I am not able to do it. I have searched on google but no answer found.
The part of code from model.py

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    @staticmethod
    def insert_roles():
        roles = {
            'User': (Permission.FOLLOW |
                     Permission.COMMENT |
                     Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES, True),
            'Moderator': (Permission.FOLLOW |
                          Permission.COMMENT |
                          Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES |
                          Permission.MODERATE_COMMENTS, False),
            'Administrator': (0xff, False)
        }
        for r in roles:
            role = Role.query.filter_by(name=r).first()
            if role is None:
                role = Role(name=r)
            role.permissions = roles[r][0]
            role.default = roles[r][1]
            db.session.add(role)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name




class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    avatar_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

Whenever I try to add an column by running command
`python manage.py db upgrade` to it; it throws the following **error:**

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table
>   roles already exists [SQL: u'\nCREATE TABLE roles (\n\tid INTEGER NOT
>   NULL, \n\tname VARCHAR(64), \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tUNIQUE
>   (name)\n)\n\n']

How can I add column to my database?

Comment: Did you do `python manage.py db migrate` prior to trying to upgrade?

Comment: @PattrickAllen Yes, that too gives error as "alembic.util.CommandError: Target database is not up to date"

Answer (score 0):

After `db migrate`

run `python manage.py db upgrade`.

Comment: Someone suggested that in the comments and the OP indicated that didn't work (also, you spelled upgrade wrong)

Comment: Sorry.I only see this `alembic.util.CommandError: Target database is not up to date`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is "table roles already exists". Therefore, you need to drop your db first and try to run python manage.py db upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

You must have created the database by running `db.create_all()`;

I meet the same problem and you may try my solution as follow:

1. delete the database file (.sqlite);
2. delete the migrations folder;
3. run `... db init` to create a new migrations;
4. run `... db migrate` and `... db upgrade`;

There may be some repeated operations between `db.create_all()` and the init migration. So just skip creating the tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following three commands:

```
flask db stamp head
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```